# Why is my submit form not being executed in my Meteor app?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, form-submit

I've got this HTML in my Meteor app:

```
<template name="addPerson">
   . . .
   <input id="inputbuttonPerson" name="inputbuttonPerson" type="submit" value="Save Person">
</template>
```

...and this Javascript event handler for the form submit:

```
Template.addPerson.events({'submit form': function(event, template) {
    alert('reached addPerson.submit form');
    console.log('reached addPerson.submit form');
    event.preventDefault();
    var firstname = template.find('#firstName').value;
    . . .
```

...yet the "submit" button is not firing; I see no alert, nor console log text, nor is there a record added to the MongoDB after I mash the submit button (inputbuttonPerson).

Why doesn't the Template's submit button event handler respond to the clicking of the submit button?

Comment: I don't see any `form` in the `template`, just see a submit button. Add complete code. Then use `click #inputbuttonPerson`

Comment: I think 'submit form' is better than a 'click #buttonName'; but you were right - I had erroneously omitted the "form" tag and end tag!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information you provided is not sufficient. I'll try to construct the whole picture out of what you put into the question.

Let's pretend you have a template:

```
<template name="addPerson">
    <form action="" class="form" method="">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName">
        <input type="submit" class="btn" id="inputbuttonPerson" name="inputbuttonPerson">
    </form>
</template>
```

Important:

1. There is actually a `form` element. This element is what you bind to to listen to events it fires.
2. We have an `input` with `firstName` id so we can refer to it later.
3. We don't bind any value to it explicitly, however, it's possible to bind it to a reactive data source.
4. I use your syntax to put a submit element, although, I personally would use `button` element. But it doesn't matter.

and then you define event listeners:

```
Template.addPerson.events({
    'submit form': function (event, template) {
        console.log('reached addPerson.submit form');
        console.log(event.target.firstName.value);
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Few more things to take into account:

1. We refer to `addPerson` property of `Template` object, i.e. referring precisely to the template defined above.
2. The event is `submit form` which means that it only fires when the user submits the form. It's not a simple button click. It can be fired either by `[type=submit]` element or pressing `return` key in any form field.
3. The function that is bound to the event has two parameters: `event` object and `template` instance object. Actually, no need to use the latter. Just simply `event` object is sufficient 99% time.
4. We `console.log` the value of `event.target.firstName`. The `event.target` object contains all the elements that are children of event target. Since we're listening to the form's event, target is the form, so `event.target` object contains form's children. It's possible to access form's children by their `name`s, hence `event.target.firstName`.
5. The `value` property of a particular target child extracts the `value` attribute of a DOM element. Input fields have values. The `event.target.firstName.value` expression will return whatever has been typed into the field at the moment event has been fired.
6. And `event.preventDefault()` to not get redirected to whatever URL is defined as `action` of the form.

This setup works perfectly. Please look into your code and see what particular point you have missed out. You could either misplace the elements in form hierarchy, this is what I feel to be likely according to the problem you're having.

Comment: Tushar had it; I had inadvertently omitted the "form" tags. Adding those solved the problem.